# Check for window title

Tags: c++, loops, winapi

Hello im creating program that check for opened window name but at the moment it check it like 100 times per second and i want to check it every time the window change.I know its propably becasue of infinity loop.But im new in C++ and i have no idea how to do it, can someone help me ?

```
    char wnd_title[256];
    while(1) {
        HWND hwnd=GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowText(hwnd,wnd_title,sizeof(wnd_title));
        cout << wnd_title;
    }
```

Best regards.

Comment: Dupe is tagged C# but the answers only use basic Win API, so they still apply.

Comment: ehh my function work correctly i just need to write it 1 time not 1000 times, i know that the simplest answer is paste another topic , but every problem is different not the same , thats why i dont like to post something on stack :)

Answer (score -1):

There are several things you can do to achieve that:

Best (thanks to Remy in the comments): "Another option is to use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to listen for `EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE` events. That is "more promising" than intercepting `WM_SETTEXT` messages, and less intrusive than "infiltrating"."

- simple and boring (and it seems not really what you wanted): set a timer for the request so it is called in longer periods
- propably the most promising one: Set up a [Window hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) with WH_GETMESSAGE to listen for the WM_SETTEXT which is messaged from the [SetWindowTextA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta) function
- or go full crazy and [CreateRemoteThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) and infiltrate your enemy with a trusty spy.

Comment: Another option is to use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to listen for `EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE` events. That is "more promising" than intercepting `WM_SETTEXT` messages, and less intrusive than "infiltrating".

Comment: @RemyLebeau good hint thanks! Must have skipped this on my quick research.